# Dá pra acessar o bash no Android?

Tags: android, linux

Não sou especialista em Linux. Mas se o Android usa o Kernel do Linux, subentende-se que deve ter algumas semelhanças. O terminal seria uma delas?

Comment: Somente para fortalecer o conceito, o "Android é um sistema Linux multi-usuário". Segundo esta documentação da Google: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals Observe a citação: > "The Android operating system is a multi-user Linux system in which
> each app is a different user."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma excelente forma é o adb, mas é externo ao android

para usar embarcado no proprio android:
Tem o 'bash shell x' para android:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitcubate.android.bash.installer&hl=pt_BR

ao baixar vc vai usar o botão #root shell.

Porém para você realmente ter acesso a um conjunto maior de ferramentas linux, você poderia rootear seu celular, e adicionar o busybox

'BusyBox é um aplicativo de software que fornece muitas ferramentas padrão do Unix, bem como os maiores (mas mais capazes) Utilitários Básicos da GNU. BusyBox é projetado para ser um pequeno executável para uso com o kernel do Linux, o que o torna ideal para uso com dispositivos embarcados. Tem sido auto-apelidado de "o canivete suíço de Linux embutido"."'
(http://www.androidpit.com.br/forum/644126/para-que-serve-o-busybox)

abs

Answer (score 4):

Olá,

sim é possível utilizando o `adb` veja o [aqui](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) mais infos sobre ele.

Resumindo, `adb shell` abre o `prompt` e você pode rodar os comandos, mas lembre-se que eles são restritos.

Comment: defina restritos rs

Comment: Opa, nem todos os comandos estão dispoíveis e nem todos os parâmetros são permitidos, por exemplo o comando `ls` pode receber o parâmetro `-t`, funciona no `Linux`, não funciona no `shell` do `Android`, já o parâmetro `-l` funciona sem problemas.

Comment: Ahh sim. Obrigado, man.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando as respostas já publicadas aqui na pergunta, uma maneira legal de utilizar o `adb` é você definindo como uma variável de ambiente. Assim você pode utilizar comandos `adb shell`, `adb devices`, ou qualquer outro que o `adb` disponibilize no diretório onde você está.

Como proceder:

1. Botão direito do mouse em Meu Computador > Propriedades > Configurações Avançadas do Sistema > Variáveis de Ambiente > Clique em Novo em Variáveis do Sistema.
2. Defina o nome da variável como `ADB_HOME` ou outro que preferir e o valor da variável que é o caminho do SDK do Android. No meu caso o SDK está localizado em: `D:\Android`. Salve.
3. Procure pela variável de sistema com nome `Path` e clique para alterar ela.
4. No final da linha, coloque a variável de ambiente criada anteriormente desta maneira: `%ADB_HOME%/platform-tools;`, separando com ponto e vírgula sempre as declarações nessa variável de ambiente entre diferentes variáveis de ambiente.

Exemplo de um trecho da minha variável de ambiente `Path`:

```
%JBOSS_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%PHP_HOME%
```

Entende como funciona? O `adb.exe` está localizado na pasta `platform-tools` da minha pasta `D:\Android`, defini essa pasta da raiz como uma variável de ambiente chamada `ADB_HOME` e no `Path` declarei ela e coloquei a barra com o nome da pasta `platform-tools` onde está o `adb.exe`.

No Linux, edite o seu arquivo `~/.bashrc`, exemplo:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
#AndroidDev PATH 
export PATH=${PATH}:/root/android-sdk-linux/tools 
export PATH=${PATH}:/root/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

Encerre a sessão, entre de novo e abra o Terminal informando o seguinte comando:

```
adb version
```

Se retornar corretamente a versão do adb foi configurado corretamente.